# graph theory& combinations problem- why does degree of vertex will be sum of those edges

Tags: graph-theory, combinations

> [image]

Here is the cpature from problem set, can anyone enlighten me why does the degree of each vertex under this qeustion will be all the edges differ more than two position.

what guarantee the vertex connected to all the edges?

Much appreciated for any help.

Comment: The definition of $G$ guarantees this. **By definition** two vertices are connected by an edge if and only if they differ in more than two positions, so every vertex has an edge to every vertex that differs from it in more than two positions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi, would you please share a link that I could further look into it? I only find out two vertices connected if a path link them.

Comment: You’re not paying attention to the definition of $G$ that you were given, or else you don’t realize that $E$ is the set of edges of $G$. The definition tells you exactly which vertices have edges between them: vertices $u$ and $v$ have an edge joining them if and only if $u$ and $v$ differ in more than two positions. There is nothing in it about paths.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. Cheers